# Javascript not reading/parsing price data over 6 digits

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is some code I had a freelancer to write but it's causing an issue I didn't foresee:( It reads a csv data file with pricing information (; separated), parses the data and displays it using Highcharts.  It works fine reading six digits like "$500,000" but it won't display data longer than that, "$1,000,000" for example.  What am I missing?

```
var datafile = '../data/Data.csv';  
var years, activedata, html;
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: datafile,
       data: null,
       success: function(text) {
           var fields = text.split('{$del}');
           fields.pop(fields.length);
           var headers = fields[0].split(';');
           var headkey = Array();
           var sel = document.createElement('select');
           sel.setAttribute('id', 'choice');
           for(var i = 0; i < headers.length-1; i += 1) {
              if(headers[i] != ''){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.setAttribute('value', i);
                var t = document.createTextNode(headers[i]);
                opt.appendChild(t);
                sel.appendChild(opt);
                headkey.push(Array(i,headers[i]));
              }                             
           } 
           sel.onchange = Function('parsedata(this.value)');
           var cs = document.getElementById('chartselect');
           var t = document.createTextNode('Select a Chart to View:');
           cs.appendChild(t);
           cs.appendChild(sel);
           var data = fields.slice(2, fields.length);           
           activedata = data;
           return parsedata(1);
       }
    }); 


}); 
function cleanvalue(val){
   var va = val.replace('$',"");
   return parseInt(va.replace(",",""));              
} 
function commas(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
  }  
 function parsedata(head){
           var val = $("#choice option:selected").text();
           //var title = document.getElementById('charttitle');
           var minimum = 0;
           var tx = val;
           var na = '';
            if(tx.indexOf("Sales") != -1){
                 na = 'Total Units';
                 minimum = 0;
            }else{
                 na = 'Average Prices';
                 minimum = 300000;
            }
           //title.innerHTML= tx;
           //var months = Array();           
           var us = Array();
           var usa = Array();
           var usb = Array();
           var usba = Array();
           var usbb = Array();
           var usbc = Array();
           var usc = Array();  
           var vals = '['; 
           var is2014, is2015, is2016;
           for(var j = 0; j < activedata.length; j += 1) { 
              var dataFields = activedata[j].split(';');

              var c = 0;  
              for(x=0; x <= dataFields.length; x += 1 ){


                 if(x >= head && x <= parseInt(head) + 6){
                    vals += dataFields[x]+',';
                    if(c == 0) us.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    if(c == 1) usa.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    if(c ==  2 ) usb.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    if(c == 3 && dataFields[x] != '' ) {
                       is2014 = 1;
                       usba.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    }
                    if(c == 4 && dataFields[x] != '' ) {
                       is2015 = 1;
                       usbb.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    }
                    if(c == 5 && dataFields[x] != '' ) {
                       is2016 = 1;
                       usbc.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    }
                    if(c ==  6 ) usc.push(cleanvalue(dataFields[x]));
                    c++;
                    //html += '<td style="border:thin solid #000;">' + cleanvalue(dataFields[x]) + '</td>';
                 }

              } 
           }
           years = [{
                type: 'column',
                name: '2013',
                yAxis:1,
                data: usb
            }]
           if(is2014 == 1){
             years.push({
                type: 'column',
                name: '2014',
                yAxis:1,
                data: usba
            }); 
           }
           if(is2015 == 1){
             years.push({
                type: 'column',
                name: '2015',
                yAxis:1,
                data: usbb
            }); 
           } 
           if(is2016 == 1){
             years.push({
                type: 'column',
                name: '2016',
                yAxis:1,
                data: usbc
            }); 
           }
```

The rest is the javascript that makes the charts. Would really appreciate some insights here...thanks

Comment: My guess is, that it has something to do with your browsers culture settings. Since "$1,000,000" has two "," in it, it is most likely that the javascript parser does not parse the number correctly in this case. Javascript uses your culture settings of your browser by default

Comment: I figured out a simple work around... Just give it clean data with no $ and , and it doesnt break the function! Works fine now. Thanks